# PRIMARY KEY мешает многострочному INSERT

Tags: mysql

Всем привет, почему когда я создаю таблицу с строкой PRIMARY KEY то немогу добавить многострочный INSERT?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
id INT(11) NOT NULL,
name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(0, 'VIDEO'),
(0, 'MUSIC'),
(0, 'SPORT');
```

пример взят из учебника

Comment: пример плохой, а значит и учебник, выкиньте.

Comment: будет работать [так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1897f1) и [так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/726b3), а так-же [так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea0fa)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `Primary Key` он уникальный для каждой записи, а вы видимо пытаетесь задать одинаковый key для всех записей

**Update**
Задайте ключевому полю автоинкремент, тогда при вставке не надо задавать ключ и можно делать многострочные вставки без задания уникальных `id`

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
   id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```